# How to get a collection from a collection in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, active-relation

I have collection of users with posts, and I'd like to get all the posts from all of the users. Is there a way to do something like this:

```
User.active.posts.unique.visible
```

Active and visible are both special scopes that I've written myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `user_id` column in your `posts` table:

```
Post.where(user_id: User.active.map(&:id)).visible
```

It will generate two SQL queries without any join (unless you use join in your `visible` scope), so it's quite efficient way.